# angular.io not reacting on firefox and working weird on ie edge

Tags: angular, firefox, microsoft-edge

if you go on the following page:

> http://beta.melard.fr

you'll we be asked to create a user (but it's a local storage mock). After that

you will notice everything works like a charm on chrome, but on firefox, only the colorwheel responds and on IE, the buttons respond but when you hover some md-button the page reload itself :/

I wonder what I am missing as a lot of people develop apps with angular for any browser...

For the braver, here is the github repo:
https://github.com/mylen/canimap

Polyfill:

```
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

Everything else is commented.

```
@angular/cli: 1.4.3
node: 6.11.2
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.4.3
@angular/cdk: 2.0.0-beta.10
@angular/common: 4.4.3
@angular/compiler: 4.4.3
@angular/core: 4.4.3
@angular/forms: 4.4.3
@angular/http: 4.4.3
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.10
@angular/platform-browser: 4.4.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.4.3
@angular/router: 4.4.3
@angular/cli: 1.4.3
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.3
@angular/language-service: 4.3.6
typescript: 2.3.4
```

Comment: check Your browsers version

Comment: What polyfills are you using? Are you using Angular-CLI?

Comment: I used ng new to bootstrap my app so angular-cli for the polyfill, look at: http://beta.melard.fr/polyfills.bundle.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was rather simple as usual.

I used md-icon:

```
  <button md-icon-button aria-label="Parking" mdTooltipPosition="below" mdTooltip="Parking" i18n="Parking|Put a parking slot">
    <md-icon class="md-24" (click)="draw('ParkingMarker')" color="color('ParkingMarker')">
      local_parking
    </md-icon>
  </button>
```

instead of

```
  <button md-icon-button aria-label="Parking" mdTooltipPosition="below" mdTooltip="Parking" i18n="Parking|Put a parking slot"
    (click)="draw('ParkingMarker')">
    <md-icon class="md-24"  color="color('ParkingMarker')">
      local_parking
    </md-icon>
  </button>
```

you have to be carreful to put the click handler on the **button** and not the **Icon**